# Jenkins/Hudson build schedule period spanning over midnight (9 p.m. till 2 a.m.)

Tags: automation, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, cronexpression

I wanted to schedule a job in Jenkins to run sometime between 18pm till 2am.

So I entered the following formula in **Build periodically/Schedule field:**

`H H(18-2) * * *`

However, when I save the job, there is an exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:719)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n must be positive
at java.util.Random.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at hudson.scheduler.Hash$1.next(Hash.java:72)
at hudson.scheduler.BaseParser.doHash(BaseParser.java:100)
at hudson.scheduler.CrontabParser.term(CrontabParser.java:328)
at hudson.scheduler.CrontabParser.expr(CrontabParser.java:180)
at hudson.scheduler.CrontabParser.startRule(CrontabParser.java:60)
... 60 more
```

for testing purposes when I entered:

`H H(0-2) * * *` it works fine.

Can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't seem to be possible at the moment, take a look at this bug:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18313

My first answer included this suggested workaround, which doesn't work:

```
H H(18-23,0-2) * * *
```

Comment: I checked and Jenkins give the following error message: 


Invalid input: "H H(18-23,0-2) * * *": line 1:10: expecting ")", found ','

I also checked semicolon (;), whitespace (' ') with the same error present.

Comment: I found a bug report on just your problem, and updated the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let's look when will they fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same problem, very fustrating, 
One suggestion is 2 schedules, I have tested this method and it works.

```
H H(18-23) * * *
H H(0-1) * * *
```

Please note that if you specify 0-1, that is from midnight to 1.59 AM

Hope this helps

Noel/

Comment: This won't run the job twice?